# Category tags with comma's

Tags: categories, loop

I have in my code the following variable to call the title of the categories.

```
<?php 
      $categories = get_the_terms($custom_args->ID, 'veranstaltungen-category');

      foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cats .= $category->name . ', ';
            echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
          }
?>
```

The problem is that in the last post of the loop I duplicated the categories and printed them all.
[image]

in fact it is printed by post from less to more.
If I use the following code fragment, I print it well but without commas

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<span>'.$category->name .'</span>';
}
```

If someone would be so kind to guide me I would be very grateful, this brings me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
$cats .= $category->name . ', ';
```

You append a name of category to variable called $cats.

But you never reset this variable. So every post appends its categories to the same variable.

So here’s how to fix this:

```
<?php
  $categories = get_the_terms($custom_args->ID, 'veranstaltungen-category');
  $cats = ''; // set empty string as  value

  foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cats .= $category->name . ', ';
        echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
  }
?>
```

Of course you can also add commas to your second code:

```
foreach ($categories as $i => $category) {
         if ( $i ) echo ', ';
         echo '<span>'.$category->name .'</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add comma this way

```
<?php 
$post_cat = get_the_terms( $custom_args->ID, 'veranstaltungen-category' );

$result_pro_cat = "";

foreach ( $post_cat as $post_cat_key => $post_cat_value ) {
    $result_pro_cat .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $post_cat_value->term_id ) ) . '">' . $post_cat_value->name . '</a>' . ', ';  
} 
echo rtrim( $result_pro_cat, ', ' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just define $cats null variable, so every time it reset the cat value null. and echo $cats out side of foreach loop. that's it.

```
      $categories = get_the_terms($custom_args->ID, 'veranstaltungen-category');
      #define blank 
      $cats = "";
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cats .= $category->name . ', ';
       }
       # echo out of foreach loop
       echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
```